# pyodbc: works in 3.7.2 but breaks in 3.11.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc, python-3.11

```
import pyodbc

my_db_path = r'C:\testing\mydb.accdb'
my_db_pw = r'djw85nawj12'

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;PWD=%s' % (my_db_path, my_db_pw))

#in python 3.7.2 (pyodbc 4.0.32)  -> works, returns conn object
#in python 3.11.3 (pyodbc 4.0.39) -> error: data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I need to get this working in 3.11.3 and I don't understand why it fails. I tried multiple variations with and without usage of raw strings. What's happening in 3.11.3?

Comment: I have found a likely cause: using pyodbc.drivers() reveals a long list of drivers for 3.7.2 but in 3.11.3 I only see `SQL Server`. Why is it different?

Comment: Alright, I found the cause: my Python 3.7.2 is a 32-bit Python installed long ago. My 3.11.3 Python is a 64-bit Python installed quite recently. On my Windows machine, I have a lot of 32-bit drivers available, but only 1 64-bit driver. I need to figure out not, how to install the 64-bit drivers :)